# Finding text in a file using perl program

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file given below:

```
>AAF88103.1 zinc finger protein 226 [Homo sapiens]
MNMFKEAVTFKDVAVAFTEEELGLLGPAXRKLYRDVMVENFRNLLSVGHPPFKQDVSPIERNEQLWIMTT
ATRRQGNLGEKNQSKLITVQDRESEEELSCWQIWQQIANDLTRCQDSMINNSQCHKQGDFPYQVGTELSI
QISEDENYIVNKADGPNNTGNPEFPILRTQDSWRKTFLTESQRLNRDQQISIKNKLCQCKKGVDPIGWIS
HHDGHRVHKSEKSYRPNDYEKDNMKILTFDHNSMIHTGQKSYQCNECKKPFSDLSSFDLHQQLQSGEKSL
TCVERGKGFCYSPVLPVHQKVHVGEKLKCDECGKEFSQGAHLQTHQKVHVIEKPYKCKQCGKGFSRRSAL
NVHCKVHTAEKPYNCEECGRAFSQASHLQDHQRLHTGEKPFKCDACGKSFSRNSHLQSHQRVHTGEKPYK
CEECGKGFICSSNLYIHQRVHTGEKPYKCEECGKGFSRPSSLQAHQGVHTGEKSYICTVCGKGFTLSSNL
QAHQRVHTGEKPYKCNECGKSFRRNSHYQVHLVVHTGEKPYKCEICGKGFSQSSYLQIHQKAHSIEKPFK
CEECGQGFNQSSRLQIHQLIHTGEKPYKCEECGKGFSRRADLKIHCRIHTGEKPYNCEECGKVFRQASNL
LAHQRVHSGEKPFKCEECGKSFGRSAHLQAHQKVHTGDKPYKCDECGKGFKWSLNLDMHQRVHTGEKPYK
CGECGKYFSQASSLQLHQSVHTGEKPYKCDVCGKVFSRSSQLQSHQRVHTGEKPYKCEICGKSFSWRSNL
TVHHRIHVGDKSYKSNRGGKNIRESTQEKKSIK.
```

In this file i am trying to look for a sequence i.e: **CDECGKEFSQGAHLQTHQKVH**
I have to hardcode this pattern in the program and then look for it, my code is as follows

```
    open FILE1, "file.fasta" or die;

while (my $line= <FILE1>) {

chomp $line;

}

if ($line =~ /CDECGKEFSQGAHLQTHQKVH/) {
    print "The protein contains the domain";
}else{
    print "The protein doesn't contain the domain";
}
```

Now this pattern occurs in the sequence but i always get the message "The protein doesn't contain the domain". Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11115501).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $line evaluation occurs outside of the loop... Give this a try:

```perl
my $found = 0;
open(my $fh, '<', 'file.fasta') or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /CDECGKEFSQGAHLQTHQKVH/) {
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ($found == 1) {
    print "The protein contains the domain";
} else {
    print "The protein doesn't contain the domain";
}
```

Comment: `my $found = 0;`

Comment: fixed... in my defence it's been 5 years since I last played find the missing semicolon... Thanks!

Comment: Please also check [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_2016_a4.pdf) page 139 for usage of `open`.

Comment: Thank you it does what i want but in your opinion is it a good idea to pass such a long string in regex pattern?

Comment: @perly this does not consume the entire file all at once. It consumes the contents of the file line by line. See "Reading Files as Iterator' in https://www.devglan.com/python/file-handling-in-python for an explanation.